# How to make it so when timer ends, UIViewController switches?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers.

View controller 1 has a button that goes to view controller 2 (which works perfectly).

I have a timer that counts down from 15 on view controller 2.

How can I make it so that when the timer hits 0, it automatically switches screens (and sends one integer) to the 3rd view controller?

Is there any code that I can insert into the method below so that it will switch to my third view controller automatically sending the integer as well?

```
if(secondsCount==0)
{

    [countDownTimer invalidate];

    countDownTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`

Answer (score 0):

You should make a @property timeValue in your third view controller to pass the integer.

```
if(secondsCount==0)
{

[countDownTimer invalidate];
countDownTimer = nil;
ViewController *viewController = [ViewController alloc]init];
viewController.timeValue = //enter integer here
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. im sorry but im very new to this. i skipped the time value for now so its exactly what you typed in (minus the timevalue line) i just want to get it to switch views first. when i ran it, the timer counted down to 15 and when it hit 0 there was a black screen :\?

Comment: did you change ViewController to the name of your third view controller class?

Comment: Well I havent yet created my thirdviewcontroller, so i was just testing it with my first one, and so i used the name of my first viewcontroller class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` to perform a push or pop of your view controller stack. If you need to cancel before the method is invoked, call `+[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:]`.

Something like (in your second view controller)

```
-(void)goToNextViewController
{
    UIViewController * nextViewController = [ [ MyViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:... bundle:nil ] ] ;
    newViewController.theNumber = /* number */
    [ self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES ] ;
}

-(void)startTimer
{
   [ self performSelector:@selector(goToNextViewController) withObject:nil afterDelay:15.0 ] ;
}

-(void)cancelTimer
{
    [ NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self ] ;
}
```